# Angular 8 Websocket user typing event using rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, chat, rxjs6

I am building a chat app in Angular 8 via Websocket on a .Net backend. I need some help trying to get "User typing..." event from Angular to the socket. My socket server needs to receive when the user has started typing and when they stopped which it will pass to the recipient. I have a basic reactive form with a single input control which gives me valueChanges event. I have tried many possible combinations of RxJS operators to acheive this but cant make it to work. Please help.

The closest i have gotten is below.

```
this.newMessageForm.get('message').valueChanges
  .pipe(
    first(),
    tap(value => console.log('User is typing...')),
    debounceTime(1000)
  )
  .subscribe(value => {
    console.log('User has stopped typing');
  });
```

The above gives me start typing event by giving me the first value of the stream but it doesn't reset if the user stops and starts typing again. I am new to Rxjs. Please help...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you are thinking too complicated.

So I've tried something easier with a helper function:

```js
// ......

private IsTyping : boolean; // private Variable

// ......
  this.newMessageForm.get('message').valueChanges
.pipe(
    tap(value => this.checkTyping(true)),
    debounceTime(1000))
  .subscribe(value => {
    this.checkTyping(false);
  });
// ......

checkTyping(isTyping: boolean) {
  if (isTyping !== this.IsTyping) {
    this.IsTyping = isTyping;

    if (isTyping) {
      console.log("User is typing...");
    } else {
      console.log("User has stopped typing");
    }
  }
}
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-3navec)

Comment: Wow you were right. I was overthinking. This took care of it.....Thanks a ton man....